USER_RIGHTS Assignment Through PowerShell Script
Due to my job, i have to make hundreds of computers CIS compliant up to Level IG3. to do this user rights have to be assigned methodically through a PowerShell script. the script I have created manages to edit the rights that have already been configured through GPO or ones configured by default (By configured I mean having a user attached to them). My issue arises when I try and add a user to a right that does not have any other user or SID attached to it. My guess is that this is because SECEDIT doesn't export rights with no SID attached to them but I'm not completely sure.
My current Script is:
$userRight = "SeRestorePrivilege*"

$code = (Start-Process secedit -ArgumentList "/export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg c:\policies.inf" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

$sid = "S-1-5-32-544"

$policy = Get-Content C:\policies.inf
$newpol = @()

if (-NOT ($userRight -In $policy)){

  foreach ($line in $policy){

    if ($line -like "[Privilege Rights]"){
      
      $line += "`n"
      $line = $line + $userRight
      $line += "= "
      $line = $line + ",*$sid"
    }
  $newpol += $line
  }
$newpol | Out-File C:\policies.inf -Force

$code = (Start-Process secedit -ArgumentList "/configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg C:\policies.inf /areas USER_RIGHTS /log C:\policies.log" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

Remove-Item -Path c:\policies.inf -Force

} Else {

foreach ($line in $policy)
    {
        if ($line -like $userRight)
            {
                $line = $line.replace($line.split("=")[1],"")
                $line += "= "
                $line = $line + ",*$sid"
        $line = $line + ", *S1-1-0"
            }

        $newpol += $line
    }

$newpol | Out-File C:\policies.inf -Force

$code = (Start-Process secedit -ArgumentList "/configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg C:\policies.inf /areas USER_RIGHTS /log C:\policies.log" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode

Remove-Item -Path c:\policies.inf -Force
}

gpupdate


Any help will be appreciated

Since you are using PowerShell I suggest giving ActiveDirectory Module a try in place of secedit

@Daniel Thanks for the help, I'll have to give this a try however these computers will be spread across multiple different AD's as they are for separate companies.
